# Rust type casting in a match statement

Tags: rust

I'm trying to do this using the `etherparse` library:

```
            match deserialized_packet.payload_ether_type() {
                Some(payload_type) => match payload_type {
                    EtherType::Arp as u16 => {

                    },
                    _ => continue
                },
                None => continue,
            }
```

but Rust doesn't seem to like that very much, as I get this error: `'!', '(', ')', ',', '::', '{' or '|' expected, got 'as'`. How can I cast the Arp to a u16 in the match statement?

By the way, it works to use `ether_type::Arp` as it's defined as a constant instead of a value in an enum, but the documentation says the EtherType enum can be cast to a u16, and I think it looks cleaner to use the enum instead of a constant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Match arms are *patterns,* not expressions.  `as` cannot be used in patterns in this way.

Instead of casting the `EtherType` variants to `u16`, use [`EtherType::from_u16()`](https://docs.rs/etherparse/latest/etherparse/enum.EtherType.html#method.from_u16) to convert the `u16` to `EtherType`.  Note that this function returns an `Option` because conversion can fail if the value is out of range; the `Option::and_then()` utility is useful here:

```
match deserialized_packet.payload_ether_type().and_then(EtherType::from_u16) {
    Some(payload_type) => match payload_type {
        EtherType::Arp => {

        },
        _ => continue
    },
    None => continue,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the value in a constant, as constants can be matched against:

```rust
match deserialized_packet.payload_ether_type() {
    Some(payload_type) => {
        const ARP: u16 = EtherType::Arp as u16;
        match payload_type {
            ARP => {},
            _ => continue
        },
    }
    None => continue,
}
```

On nightly, you can use inline const:

```rust
#![feature(inline_const_pat)]

match deserialized_packet.payload_ether_type() {
    Some(payload_type) => match payload_type {
        const { EtherType::Arp as u16 }  => {},
        _ => continue
    },
    None => continue,
}
```